# how to reduce h264 annex B NAL unit sizes to avoid IP fragmentation?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, voip, h.264

I'm trying to stream a video over to a terminal using RTP. The video is coded in h.246. I'm using ffmpeg to extract the byte stream according to h.264 annex B :

```
ffmpeg -i test.h264 -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -an out.h264
```

This works fine, but some NAL units are bigger than the network  MTU and thus they get
fragmented by IP when being sent over to the terminal. The terminal seems a little bit lazy and discards fragmented datagrams making the video playback awful.

So basically I need a way to reduce the NAL unit size, any ideas ?

Comment: size of NAL is decidec by encoder at the time of encoding, nothing can be done at bitstream level. only solution seems like re-encoding.

Comment: @rajneesh thanks for your comment. I've done that. I decoded the video into raw and then reencoded it as h246, but I still get these huge (around 3kb) SPS frames that I can not reduce.

Comment: enable multiple slice, each slice can then be put into separate NAL unit.you can choose number of slice per picture according to picture-size, bitrate.

Comment: @rajneesh I've been trying to do what you suggested with no luck, I'm using x264 for the encoding but I still get huge SPSs... this is the line I'm trying : $ x264 --profile baseline --input-res 352x288 --slices 8 --slice-max-size 1200 -o test.h264 --fps 15 --bitrate 90 video.yuv